# How to weight these numbers to evenly allocate them on a continuum?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash being returned with mood and probability as the keys, and (positive/neutral/negative) and (0..1 as float) as the values respectively. I'd like to convert all values to whole numbers ranging from 0 to 100, where the numbers will be roughly in the following ranges based on mood-probability scoring:

```
0-40 - negative
41-60 - neutral
61-100 - positive
```

I was thinking that to achieve this, I could do something like the following, but this won't work.

```
if
    @response["mood"] == positive
    @object.score = @response["prob"] * 100 * certain_weighting
  elsif
    @response["mood"] == neutral
    @object.score = @response["prob"] * 100 * certain_weighting
  else
    @response["mood"] == negative
    @object.score = @response["prob"] * 100 * certain_weighting
  object.save
end
```

Is there any way to compute this without having to refer to a large table that will consist of rows and rows of conditionals like:

```
if @response["mood"] == positive && @response["prob"] > 0.9
   @object.score = #some_predefined_number_like_98
elsif @response["mood"] == positive && @response["prob"] > 0.8
   @object.score = #some_predefined_number_like_93
#etc.
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more where the mood comes in? What's the relationship between mood and probability? Because I can't really understand why you have all those ifs in there..

Comment: It's a response from a sentiment analysis API. Each text that's parsed gets assigned a mood, such as positive, and a probability (such as 0.5) that the mood is indeed positive. A response of [positive,0.9] is more likely to be positive than a response of [positive,0.1]

Answer (score 0):

So I think I now understand. your `certain_weighting` differs per mood is this correct?

Then you could simply create a hash that contains these weights:

```
weights = {
  "positive" => 98,
  "neutral" => 66,
  "negative" => 44
}
@object.score = @response["prob"] * 100 * weights[@response["mood"]]
```

Comment: That won't work because if the response mood is negative and probability is 0.5 then that will give (0.5 * 100 * 0.44) which gives a score of 22/100. If the mood is negative but the probability is 0.9, then the score is 39.6. A response whose probability is more likely to be negative cannot have a higher score than a response whose chances of being negative are 50-50.

Comment: I just put in some random numbers.. My code was supposed to be a more concise version of your first code snippet.. 
But I guess your problem is the math not ruby. Try thinking of a mathematical function that will reliably calculate what you want and then convert that to code..

Comment: That is what I was looking for initially.